# Choosing an Appropriate FIFO Data Structure

Tags: c++, data-structures

I need a FIFO structure that supports indexing.  Each element is an array of data that is saved off a device I'm reading from.  The FIFO has a constant size, and at start-up each element is zeroed out.

Here's some pseudo code to help understand the issue:

```
Thread A (Device Reader):
1. Lock the structure.
2. Pop oldest element off of FIFO (don't need it).
3. Read next array of data (note this is a fixed size array) from the device.
4. Push new data array onto the FIFO.
5. Unlock.

Thread B (Data Request From Caller):
1. Lock the structure.
2. Determine request type.
3. if (request = one array) memcpy over the latest array saved (LIFO).
4. else memcpy over the whole FIFO to the user as a giant array (caller uses arrays).
5. Unlock.
```

Note that the FIFO shouldn't be changed in Thread B, the caller should just get a copy, so data structures where pop is destructive wouldn't necessarily work without an intermediate copy.

My code also has a boost dependency already and I am using a lockfree spsc_queue elsewhere.  With that said, I don't see how this queue would work for me here given the need to work as a LIFO in some cases and also the need to memcpy over the entire FIFO at times.

I also considered a plain  `std::vector`, but I'm worried about performance when I'm constantly pushing and popping.

Comment: If it is of fixed size [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) with your own pop logic, or [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) but you'd have to do the size checks.

Comment: If efficiency is important you could look into a circular buffer using vector as a base. For most purposes, deque is ok.

Comment: Seems a bit strange for the producer of the data to determine when data in the shared data area is to be removed. Normally that would be the consumer's role since the consumer knows when it has read the data. And since your consumer may read more than one entry at a time, how do you prevent duplicated data being read?

Comment: The caller (consumer) asynchronously requests data at a rate of about once every couple of seconds.  The device streams much faster and when a request comes in, I need the freshest data.

Comment: If you always want the freshest data for the consumer, is a FIFO really the data structure you want? Or perhaps the incoming data rate along with a limited FIFO size will cause the data in the FIFO read by the consumer to be reasonably fresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `boost::circular_buffer` which is a fixed size container that supports random access iteration, constant time insert and erase at the beginning and end. You can use it as a FIFO with `push_back()`, read `back()` for the latest data saved and iterate over the whole container via `begin(), end()` or using `operator[]`.

But at start-up the elements are not zeroed out. It has in my opinion an even more convenient interface. The container is empty at first and insertion will increase size until it reaches max size.

Answer (score 2):

One point not clear in the question is the compiler target, whether or not the solution is restricted to partial C++11 support (like VS2012), or full support (like VS2015). You mentioned boost dependency, which lends similar features to older compilers, so I'll rely on that and speak generally about options on the assumption that boost may provide what a pre-C++11 compiler may not, or you may elect C++11 features like the now standardized mutex, lock, threads and shared_ptr.

There's no doubt in my mind that the primary tool for the FIFO (which, as you stated, may occasionally need LIFO operation) is the `std::deque`. Even though the deque supports reasonably efficient dynamic expansion and shrinking of storage, contrary to your primary requirement of a static size, it's main feature is the ability to function as both FIFO and LIFO with good performance in ways vectors can't as easily manage. Internally most implementations provide what may be analogized as a collection of smaller vectors which are marshalled by the deque to function as if a single vector container (for subscripting) while allowing for double ended pushing and popping with efficient memory management. It can be tempting to use a vector, employing a circular buffer technique for fixed sizes, but any performance improvement is minimal, and deque is known to be reliable.

Your point regarding destructive pops isn't entirely clear to me. That could mean several things. `std::deque` offers `back` and `front` as a peek to what's at the ends of the deque, without destruction. In fact, they're required to look because deque's `pop_front` and `pop_back` only remove elements, they don't provide access to the element being popped. Taking an element and popping it is a two step process on `std::deque`. An alternate meaning, however, is that a read only requester needs to pop strictly as a means of navigation, not destruction, which is not really a pop, but a traversal. As long as the structure is under lock, that is easily managed with iterators or indexes. Or, it could also mean you need a independent copy of the queue.

Assuming some structure representing device data:

```
struct DevDat { .... };
```

I'm immediately faced with that curious question, should this not be a generic solution? It doesn't matter for the sake of discussion, but it seems the intent is an odd combination of application specific operation and a generalized thread-safe stack "machine", so I'll suggest a generic solution which is easily translated otherwise (that is, I suggest  template classes, but you could easily choose non-templates if preferred). These psuedo code examples are sparse, just illustrating container layout ideas and proposed concepts.

```
class SafeStackBase
{ protected: std::mutex sync;
};

template <typename Element>
class SafeStack : public SafeStackBase
{ public:  
  typedef std::deque< Element > DeQue;

  private:
  DeQue    que;

};
```

SafeStack could handle any kind of data in the stack, so that detail is left for Element declaration, which I illustrate with typedefs:

```
typedef std::vector< DevDat >         DevArray;
typedef std::shared_ptr< DevArray >   DevArrayPtr;

typedef SafeStack< DevArrayPtr >      DeviceQue;
```

Note I'm proposing vector instead of array because I don't like the idea of having to choose a fixed size, but std::array is an option, obviously.

The SafeStackBase is intended for code and data that isn't aware of the users data type, which is why the mutex is stored there. It could easily part of the template class, but the practice of placing non-type aware data and code in a non-template base helps reduce code bloat when possible (functions which don't use Element, for example, need not be expanded in template instantiations). I suggest the DevArrayPtr so that the arrays can be "plucked out" of the queue without copying the arrays, then shared and distributed outside the structure under shared_ptr's shared ownership. This is a matter of illustration, and does not adequately deal with questions regarding content of those arrays. That could be managed by DevDat, which could marshal reading of the array data, while limiting writing of the array data to an authorized friend (a write accessor strategy), such that Thread B (a reader only) is not carelessly able to modify the content. In this way it's possible to provide these arrays without copying data..just return a copy of the DevArrayPtr for communal access to the entire array. This also supports returning a container of DevArrayPtr's supporting ThreadB point 4 (copy the whole FIFO to the user), as in:

```
typedef std::vector< DevArrayPtr >    QueArrayVec;
typedef std::deque< DevArrayPtr >     QueArrayDeque;
typedef std::array< DevArrayPtr, 12 > QueArrays;
```

The point is that you can return any container you like, which is merely an array of pointers to the internal `std::array< DevDat >`, letting `DevDat` control read/write authorization by requiring some authorization object for writing, and if this copy should be operable as a FIFO without potential interference with Thread A's write ownership, `QueArrayDeque` provides the full feature set as an independent FIFO/LIFO structure.

This brings up an observation about Thread A. There you state lock is step 1, while unlock is step 5, but I submit that only steps 2 and 4 are really required under lock. Step 3 can take time, and even if you assume that is a short time, it's not as short as a pop followed by a push. The point is that the lock is really about controlling the FIFO/LIFO queue structure, and not about reading data from the device. As such, that data can be fashioned into DevArray, which is THEN provided to SafeStack to be pop/pushed under lock.

Assume code inside SafeStack:

```
typedef std::lock_guard< std::mutex >  Lock; // I use typedefs a lot

void StuffIt( const Element & e ) 
{ Lock l( sync );
  que.pop_front();
  que.push_back( e );    
}
```

`StuffIt` does that simple, generic job of popping the front, pushing the back, under lock. Since it takes an `const Element &`, step 3 of Thread A is already done. Since Element, as I suggest, is a DevArrayPtr, this is used with:

```
DeviceQue  dq;

auto p = std::make_shared<DevArray>();

dq.StuffIt( p );
```

How the `DevArray` is populated is up to it's constructor or some function, the point is that a `shared_ptr` is used to transport it.

This brings up a more generic point about SafeStack. Obviously there is some potential for standard access functions, which could mimic std::deque, but the primary job for SafeStack is to lock/unlock for access control, and do something while under lock. To that end, I submit a generic functor is sufficient to generalize the notion. The preferred mechanics, especially with respect to boost, is up to you, but something like (code inside SafeStack):

```
bool LockedFunc( std::function< bool(DevQue &)> f )
{
 Lock l( sync );
 f( que );
}
```

Or whatever mechanics you like for calling a functor taking a DevQue as a parameter. This means you could fashion callbacks with complete access to the deque (and it's interface) while under lock, or provide functors or lambdas which perform specific tasks under lock.

The design point is to make SafeStack small, focused on that minimal task of doing a few things under lock, taking most any kind of data in the queue. Then, using that last point, provide the array under shared_ptr to provide the service of Thread B steps 3 and 4.

To be clear about that, keep in mind that whatever is done to the shared_ptr to copy it is similar to what can be done to simple POD types, like ints, with respect to containers. That is, one could loop through the elements of the DevQue fashioning a copy of those elements into another container in the same code which would do that for a container of integers (remember, it's a member function of a template - that type is generic). The resulting work is only copying pointers, which is less effort than copying entire arrays of data.

Now, step 4 isn't QUITE clear to me. It appears to say that you need to return a DevArray which is the accumulated content of all entries in the queue. That's trivial to arrange, but it might work a little better with a vector (as that's dynamically expandable), but as long as the std::array has sufficient room, it's certainly possible.

However, the only real difference between such an array and the queue's native "array of arrays" is how it is traversed (and counted). Returning one Element (step 3) is quick, but since step 4 is indicated under lock, that's a bit more than most locked functions should really do if they don't have to.

I'd suggest SafeStack should be able to provide a copy of que (a DeQue typedef), which is quick. Then, outside of the lock, Thread B has a copy of the DeQue ( a std::deque< DevArrayPtr > ) to fashion into it's own "giant array".

Now, more about that array. To this point I've not adequately dealt with marshalling it. I've just suggested that DevDat does that, but this may not be adequate. Certainly the content of the std::array or std::vector conveying a collection of DevDats could be written. Perhaps that deserves it's own outer structure. I'll leave that to you, because the point I've made is that SafeStack is now focused on it's small task (lock/access/unlock) and can take anything which can be owned by a share_ptr (or POD's and copyable objects). In the same way SafeStack is an outer shell marshalling a std::deque with a mutex, some similar outer shell could marshal read only access to the std::vector or std::array of DevDats, with a kind of write accessor used by Thread A. That could be a simple as something that only allows construction of the std::array to create it's content, after which read only access could be all that's provided.