# Synchronization Mechanism For "data ready" Flag?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, locking

Consider the following pseudo-code in C++:

```
// somewhere in common code, properly scoped
boost::mutex data_ready_lock;
bool data_ready;

// Thread 1:
void SomeThreadFunc() {
  // ... push data onto a shared data structure that is properly locked
  data_ready_lock.lock();
  data_ready = true;
  data_ready_lock.unlock();
}

// Thread 2:  (actually a function called from the main() thread)
// Returns the number of bytes written to output_data
size_t RequestData(uint8_t* const output_data) {
  data_ready_lock.lock();
  if (data_ready) {
    // reset the flag, so I don't read out the same data twice
    data_ready = false;
    data_ready_lock.unlock();
    // copy over data, etc.
    return kDataSize;
  } else {
    data_ready_lock.unlock();
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?  I was thinking about condition variables, but I need the ability to reset the flag to ensure that back to back calls to RequestData() don't yield the same data.

As always, thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Since you are using boost why don't you use a [lock free queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html)?

Comment: The data isn't a FIFO per se and I need the ability to access into the queue.  For example, the caller has two request_data calls.  One will give you the whole data set, and another will give you only the most recent piece of data pushed (i.e. a LIFO).

Comment: What do you mean by better? You want event-driven call schedule for RequestData?

Comment: Just wondering if there's any simpler and/or more efficient way to accomplish my goal of having calls to RequestData not read out duplicated data or return garbage before anything is pushed.

Comment: Why don't you simply remove the data when you read it? And have writer signalling through condition variable when new stuff comes in?

Comment: So there are two ways the caller can access the data (and maybe I didn't explain this right).  First, the caller can request ALL the data.  Basically I copy over the entire FIFO into a 2D array that the caller can then use.  The other way is that the caller is only interested in the most recent element.  As a result, the data structure is acting like a LIFO in this case and I return the last element.  However, I still need that last element in the structure for any subsequent calls to get the entire data structure (i.e., return the last N sets of data encountered).

Comment: Did I understand this right, the the second form can only return one last datum, i.e. you can not really keep popping with it? If I am correct, I believe, you might split up the structures, and have the queue and a single data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the flag is the only your concern then you might try using `atomic`.

```
// somewhere in common code, properly scoped
boost::atomic< bool > data_ready(false); // can be std::atomic and std::memory_order_* below

// Thread 1:
void SomeThreadFunc() {
  // ... push data onto a shared data structure that is properly locked
  data_ready.store(true, boost::memory_order_release);
}

// Thread 2:  (actually a function called from the main() thread)
// Returns the number of bytes written to output_data
size_t RequestData(uint8_t* const output_data) {
  if (data_ready.exchange(false, boost::memory_order_acquire)) {
    // copy over data, etc.
    return kDataSize;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

However, in a real code you will have a race between the 'push data' and 'copy over data' pieces of code, unless they are synchronized separately.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your end goal is, but maybe using an actual thread-safe queue would simplify your code.  Here is one:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html

Comment: No go for what I'm trying to do.  This question should provide more context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745282/choosing-an-appropriate-fifo-data-structure

Comment: The question you linked to only describes a proecure and data structure you want to use.  It doesn't say what your end goal is, or what problem would be solved by your efforts.  See the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).